# difference in program behavior when run from python script and from windows

Tags: python, windows, logging, exe

Some background:
A program runs a manufacturing machine. This program runs on windows XP.  The program controls the machine and writes a simple manufacturing log.
I wrote a python script that asks the user to enter current manufacturing project name.  the script writes project name to log file.  This way, I have "project deviders" in the log file, and i can know which ,manufacturing data belongs to which  project.
The script works fine: project names are written to log file if not exist there before, and machine program executes.
Problem is, that the program does not write manufacturing data to log file when run from script. Only when run from windows.
I tried running two instances of the program: one from windows and one from script. Script writes project name to file successfuly, and windows run program writes data to file successfuly. So i think it's not a problem of the log file locked by the script.  I also checked that both programs run under same user, so it's not a credentials problem.
Here's the script:

```
file = open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\SteelUsage.bsu", "a+")
input = raw_input("Please enter project name:")
input = input.upper ()
for line in file.readlines():
        if input in line:
            print "Project name already exists, executing BadePanel"
            import time
            time.sleep(4)
            import subprocess
            subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
            sys.exit(0)
file.write (input+"\n")
print "Project name written to file, executing BadePanel"
import time
time.sleep(4)
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
sys.exit(0)
file.close()
```

I also tried using import os with os.system, and import suprocess with subprocess.call, instead of subprocess.Popen
Both gave same result.
Thank you

My code is strange because i am not a programmer, and this is only my second python script :)   I changed the code according to eryksun, joel and caenyon's advice:

```
file = open("C:\\Documents and settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\SteelUsage.bsu", "a+")
import time
import subprocess
input = raw_input("Please enter project name:")
input = input.upper ()
for line in file.readlines():
        if input in line:
            print "Project name already exists, executing BadePanel"
            import time
            time.sleep(4)
            file.close()
            subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
            exit()
file.write (input+"\n")
print "Project name written to file, executing BadePanel"
time.sleep(4)
file.close()
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Documents and Settings\\User1\\Desktop\\BPanel\BadePanel\\BadePanel.exe'])
exit()
```

But i stll get the same result..

Comment: FYI, don't hard code the directory. The application directory can be determined from `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))`. Other files can be opened relative to this directory, e.g. `os.path.join(appdir, "SteelUsage.bsu")`. Also, move your imports to the top of the script. It's pointless to import the same module repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: There are a couple of strange things about your code.  First, do your imports at the top, and don't ever import in a loop.  They won't hurt, but they only import once anyway.  Second, sys.exit(0) will exit your program, so your loop will stop first time you get a hit on input.  Also, your code doesn't import sys, so this isn't your complete code.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: My code is strange because i am not a programmer, and this is only my second python script :)

Comment: hi, i chnged the code as you can see in my edited post.. thanks for your adice

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program BadePanel to write to the Steelusage.bsu-file, you should close the file from the python script before you call the BadePanel.exe. If you don't do this, the file will still be opened by your script and the exe you call won't be able to write data to the file.

Comment: This could be the case, but it depends on how the program expects to share access to the file. Python opens files with read and write sharing.